# Where are the concentrations of digital companies in the UK?

Tags: data-request, uk

[New research](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-23399134) published this weekend suggests that the UK currently has 270,000 digital companies out of about [2.1 million total businesses](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/bus-register/uk-business/2011/sum-ukbusiness-2011.html).

But does anyone have access to how many people are employed in these digital firms and where they are located?  [This article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/economics/10194461/Digital-firms-importance-to-UK-economy-underestimated.html) suggests that there are hotspots in London, south-east England, Manchester, Middlesbrough & Aberdeen.  But is there more detail?

Comment: What do you mean by digital companies?

Comment: Note that the "New research" link is dead but the article can be [viewed via Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-23399134). The article provides the answer to your question @DeerHunter, "digital company" = "technology firm". The relevant [NIESR press release](http://niesr.ac.uk/press/digital-economy-40-cent-bigger-official-statistics-suggest-11498) is also informative.

Comment: Have just answered this question but now it occurs to me that it does not especially pertain to Open Data. Any suggestions as to where in the Stack Exchange network it would belong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [original article](http://niesr.ac.uk/publications/measuring-uk%E2%80%99s-digital-economy-big-data#.Ue28xNKKqzk) from the National Institute of Economic and Social Research (there's also a [direct link to the PDF](http://niesr.ac.uk/sites/default/files/publications/SI024_GI_NIESR_Google_Report12.pdf)) has more detail on the geographic distribution of UK technology firms in the form of hotspot maps by Travel to Work Area. This is among a lot of other well presented information including breakdown of technology firms by sector, and growth rates of the "digital economy".

I suspect the articles you cite in your question did not look beyond the summary of key findings. Always look to the original published report as a primary source.